# looping through year and month by file timestamp mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, list, loops

I have a following table.
[file table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr27u.jpg)

In i want to arrange like this

```
<ul>year1
      <ul>month1
     <li>filename </i>
     <li>filename </i>
     <li>filename </i>
     </ul>
     <ul>month2
     <li>filename </i>
    <li>filename </i>
   </ul>
   .............
   ..............
   <ul>month12
   <li>filename </i>

   <li>filename </i>
   </ul>
   </ul>

   <ul>year2
   <ul>month1
   <li>filename </i>
   <li>filename </i>
   <li>filename </i>
   </ul>
   <ul>month2
   <li>filename </i>

   <li>filename </i>
   </ul>
   .............
   ..............
   <ul>month12
   <li>filename </i>

   <li>filename </i>
   </ul>
   </ul>
```

And so on.
Year and month must be present according to file corresponding date stamp.
I tried using while loop it works fine for year (using EXTRACT(YEAR FROM uploaddate) AS OrderYear) but after this another loop of month repeats according to year which i don't want. So what is the solution for this.I am using php mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an array of the data first, and then loop through them to build the HTML.

```
$dataarray = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($row['uploaddate']));
    $month = date('F', strtotime($row['uploaddate']);

    $dataarray[$year][$month][] = $row['filename'];
}

foreach($dataarray as $year => $months)
{
    echo '<ul>'; //etc.....

    foreach($months as $monthname => $filenames)
    {
        //put one more loop for the filenames in here
    }
}
```

Note: The code can be improved a bit, I just did it quickly.

Note: This is very "arrow" like in nature, so you might want to find ways to optimize once you get it working.

Comment: Now I update my code a bit I add categories and subcat. to it.category has own table and subcat also have its own but contains index of category. I loop through such that  year->month->category->subcat->file name. The new problem is here filename repeated itself many number of time. year month etc works fine.How I prevent this behavior.

Comment: Im not sure why your file name is repeating, but Im sure its just a logic issue.